# Reledmac - Arbitrary Paragraph numbers/labels?

Tags: counters, reledmac

I am editing with Reledmac two different versions of the same text. I am editing them both as independent texts, rather than having one be in the apparatus of the other. One of the two versions occasionally has some paragraphs that the other is missing.

I would like to be able to give these paragraphs a different label from the normal paragraph number - For instance, if version a has a paragraph after paragraph 1 which version b doesn't have, I would like to be able to call this paragraph 1a.
I have tried `\setcounter{pstart}{value}` but it only accepts numbers for the value; and I have also tried replacing `\numberpstarttrue` with `\labelpstarttrue`, putting `\label{1a}` in various places, but it doesn't appear to print the label anywhere.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\begin{document}
\numberpstarttrue 
\beginnumbering
\pstart
This is paragraph 1.
\pend
\pstart
I would like to call this paragraph 1a.
\pend
\pstart
And then this would be paragraph 2.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A small clarification: You tagged the question [reledpar], but your MWE doesn't use `reledpar`. Are you actually using `reledpar` or only `reledmac`? Are you typesetting the two versions of the text as parallel texts (on the left and right pages) or are you printing them separately one after another? – Solutions to your questions may differ in these two cases

Comment: @marquinho Thanks so much for your reply. No, I am using Reledmac and not Reledpar, I only added the latter as I thought the solution might work for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution that **automates** the numbering (and labelling) for you.

Right before any paragraph that needs special labelling, you can issue the new command `\specialpar`.

This command halts the conventional numbering (does not add 1 to the counter `pstart`) and advances a new counter `pstartletter` instead, which is then realized in alphabetical format ("a").

Then, we declare that `\thepstart` should always print the number *and* letter, if applicable. This means that we get "1a" at the beginning of our paragraph, as well as when we reference it elsewhere.

When performing surgery on counters and related commands, one should never break *the labeling/referencing mechanism*. In my example, I have added the option `\labelpstarttrue` and the package `hyperref`, as well as the `\label{}`s, to demonstrate that the redefinition dovetails nicely with it. Note that *this is not essential* to the solution.

This is also why I did not include the par-number separator (dot and space after "1a") directly in the definition of `\thepstart`, as `reledmac.sty` does. We want it at paragraph start, sure:

> 1a._Lorem ipsum...

but we don't want `\ref{label}` to always force a dot-and-space upon us and potentially mess with the punctuation of our writing:

> See paragraph 1a._, which is missing from document A...

(This is just a suggestion though, technically it's not strictly necessary, it's up to you whether you want to take it.)

When the special paragraph (or group thereof) is over, you can issue `\normalpar`. The counter `pstartletter` is reset to 0 and only the conventional numbers are displayed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\numberpstarttrue

\newcounter{pstartletter}
\newcommand{\specialpar}{\addtocounter{pstart}{-1}\stepcounter{pstartletter}}
\newcommand{\normalpar}{\setcounter{pstartletter}{0}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thepstart}{{\bfseries\@arabic\c@pstart\@alph\c@pstartletter}}    % no dot, for better format in label-ref
%\renewcommand{\thepstart}{{\bfseries\@arabic\c@pstart\@alph\c@pstartletter}. }     % dot included, as in reledmac.sty
\makeatother

\appto{\pstart}{. }     % for better format in label-ref

\labelpstarttrue        % for demonstration purposes
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}   % for demonstration purposes

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering

\pstart 
\label{p1}A shared paragraph, no. \ref{p1}. 
\pend

\specialpar % Execute this code before every "special" paragraph
\pstart 
\label{p1a}This is an extra paragraph, no. \ref{p1a}. 
\pend

\specialpar % Execute this code before **every** "special" paragraph
\pstart 
\label{p1b}This is another extra paragraph, no. \ref{p1b}. 
\pend
\normalpar % Execute this code at the end of **a group of** "special" paragraphs

\pstart 
\label{p2}A shared paragraph again, no. \ref{p2}. 
\pend

\pstart 
\label{p3}A shared paragraph, no. \ref{p3}. 
\pend

\specialpar
\pstart 
\label{p3a}This is one more extra paragraph, \ref{p3a}.
\pend
\normalpar

\pstart 
\label{p4}A shared paragraph again, no. \ref{p4}. 
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

[image: automatic numbering of paragraphs with optional letter]

### EDIT

I realize now that you didn't explicitly ask for an **automated numbering** of paragraphs, though. You asked for a way to change the paragraph label at will. I'm sorry for jumping to this conclusion!

You can still use the framework above and set the second label (`pstartletter`) manually. Instead of the commands `\specialpar` and `\normalpar`, use the following combinations before and after the relevant paragraphs:

```
\addtocounter{pstart}{-1}\setcounter{pstartletter}{1} % use 1 for a, 2 for b...
\pstart
This is my paragraph.
\pend
\setcounter{pstartletter}{0}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks so much for this!